# How to import and layer stack seperate ndvi bands to grass gis?

Tags: grass-gis

I have 20 separate single band NDVI files. I have to import this into GRASS and stack them  into a single 20 band image.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[r.out.gdal](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.out.gdal.html)**.

See the example on how to export group of image maps as multi-band file:

```
g.list group
i.group group=tm7 subgroup=tm7 input=tm7_10,tm7_20,tm7_30,tm7_40,tm7_50,tm7_60,tm7_70
i.group -l tm7
g.region rast=tm7_10 -p
r.out.gdal tm7 output=lsat_multiband.tif
gdalinfo lsat_multiband.tif
```